# Header LogoPathResolver does not exist

Tags: php, themes, magento2

Magento theme showing me
 `Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Theme\ViewModel\Block\Html\Header\LogoPathResolver does not exist`
error while installing martfury-magento-theme. SUMA theme works fine i have do all installation part.
admin panel also works fine.
what can do to resolve this above issue.

I have tried reinstall theme again but the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the file `vendor/magento/module-theme/ViewModel/Block/Html/Header/LogoPathResolver.php` or try to run `composer dump-autoload`

If either the file did not exist or composer return error, I suggest you to remove the `vendor` folder and reinstall packages via command `composer install`